# How to do java.nio.Bytebuffer things on c# MemoryStream

Tags: c#, java, memorystream, bytebuffer

I'm new to MemoryStream and I need to do

```
buffer.get(byte array) 
buffer.flip() 
buffer.allocate(int) 
buffer.wrap(byte array) 
buffer.asReadOnlyBuffer() 
buffer.remaining()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
here is what im using at the moment. not sure if they will work the same. I need to know if these would work, and if not, what adjustments I can make

buffer.get(byte[])

java:

```
byte[] compressed = new byte[compressedSize];
buffer.get(compressed);
```

c#:

```
byte[] compressed = new byte[compressedSize];
long oldpos = buffer.mainStream.Position; 
buffer.mainStream.Read(compressed, (int)buffer.mainStream.Position, compressedSize); 
buffer.mainStream.Position = oldpos;
```

buffer.flip()

java:

```
return (ByteBuffer)buf.flip();
```

C#:

```
ExtendedBufferReader d = new ExtendedBufferReader(buf.mainStream); 
d.mainStream.Capacity = (int)d.mainStream.Position; 
d.mainStream.Position = 0; 
return d;
```

get(byte[]) and flip()

java:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[compressedSize]; 
buffer.get(temp); 
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(temp);
```

c#:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[compressedSize]; 
long oldpos = buffer.mainStream.Position; 
buffer.mainStream.Read(temp, (int)buffer.mainStream.Position, compressedSize); 
buffer.mainStream.Position = oldpos; 
ExtendedBufferWriter data1 = new     ExtendedBufferWriter(new MemoryStream()); 
data1.WriteBytes(temp); 
data1.mainStream.Position = 0; 
ExtendedBufferReader data = new     ExtendedBufferReader(data1.mainStream);
```

buffer.remaining()

java:

```
if (buffer.remaining() >= 2) {
```

C#:

```
if ((buffer.mainStream.Length -        buffer.mainStream.Position) >= 2) {
```

buffer.asReadOnlyBuffer()

java:

```
return data.asReadOnlyBuffer();
```

C#:

```
return data;
```

Comment: `ByteBuffer.limit()` is the same as `MemoryStream.Length()`

Comment: @nick-holt Then what is buffer.capacity() on memory stream?

Comment: `MemoryStream.Capacity` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.capacity(v=vs.110).aspx